# How to temporally define a Object type more specifically?

Tags: typescript, angular

I am using Angular 2.

Usually, when I define a type, I create a interface first:

```
interface Product {
  name: string,
  count: number
}
```

then use like

```
let product: Product;
```

Now I want to temporally define a Object type. Something like this:

```
let product: Object<name: string, count: number>;
```

But this is wrong. How can I do it correctly? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're actually pretty close. It's called *Object literal* type definition  and it looks like this:

```
var product: { name : string; count: number; }
// Or if you don't like semi-colons, you can comma-delimit them
var product: { name : string, count : number }

// Later you could utilize it like normal

product = { name : 'joe', count : 5 };
```

> Interfaces are just great because they could be reused everywhere

Comment: thanks, seems like `var obj: { name : string, count: number };` also works.

Comment: oh, and a typo in your answer, `count ; 5` should be `count : 5`